# Strikethrough text in tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Please go to https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/format-custom/ and press on **Edit on CodePen**.

Strikethrough an existing text.

Why does it not work? (chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it has to do with the fonts used in that CodePen.  If you remove the `content_css` portion of the TinyMCE configuration then (a) the font changes and (b) you can see the strikethrough just fine.